# c++11: erase using a const_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, erase, const-iterator

I believe that since C++11, the `erase` function of most containers (e.g. `std::vector`) accepts a `const_iterator` as parameter:

```
iterator erase (const_iterator position);
```

Still my compilers (GCC 4.8 and Clang 3.2, both using GCC libstdc++) won't allow me to use such function, even when compiling with `--std=c++11`.

Is it a compiler/libstdc++ bug, or did I do something bad? This is a sample code:

```
#include <vector>

int main( )
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back( 1 );
    v.push_back( 2 );
    v.push_back( 3 );

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin();
    while( i != v.end() ) {
        i = v.erase( i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the implementation of the Standard Library, not with the compiler itself

Comment: @Andy: yes, if the fault is not mine, it's most probably of libstdc++. Still I'm surprised that it's a problem of libstdc++ (or of the compiler, in any case), since I could find many questions about erasing a `const_iterator`, but **all** of them predate C++11...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) and it's reported as a partial implementation for now.

<kbd>CTRL + F</kbd> with your browser and search for `N2350`.

If you are on Linux it's possible to build a development version of the `libcxx` library from the LLVM project that you can download from [here](http://libcxx.llvm.org/); I don't know if this solves any of the issues that you are experiencing but I'm proposing it as an alternative to the `libstdc++`.

Comment: You're right, I missed it. It's quite weird, though, that there are many questions about this function (on SO and all around the web), but none of them addresses its lack in `libstdc++`...

Comment: Has this been fixed by now? (June 2014?)

Comment: @JonathanLeaders: I just saw your message.  Yes, now it's fixed.