# iterator - no matching erase function in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, const-iterator

I can't exmplain this behaviour:

```
for (vector<File>::const_iterator it = this->files.begin(); it != this->files.end(); ++it) {
    if (...) erase(it); // break after, no need of ++it in else branch
}
```

where File is my own class (std not included) and this->files is vector of Files

when I compile the code I get (see **line 2**)

```
Path.cpp: In member function ‘void Path::rmFile(File&)’:
Path.cpp:190:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<File>::erase(std::vector<File>::const_iterator&)’
Path.cpp:190:24: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:70:0,
             from Path.h:5,
             from Path.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:135:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator     std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = File; _Alloc =     std::allocator<File>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<File*,     std::vector<File> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = File*]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:135:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1     from ‘std::vector<File>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const File*,     std::vector<File> >}’ to ‘std::vector<File>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<File*,     std::vector<File> >}’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:147:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator     std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::vector<_Tp,     _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = File; _Alloc = std::allocator<File>; std::vector<_Tp,     _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<File*, std::vector<File> >; typename     std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = File*]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:147:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
make: *** [Path.o] Error 1
```

even the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)  says it's ok, but error **no matching function for call to std::vector::erase(std::vector::const_iterator&)** is really wierd.

I really need to be able to delete vector item by iterator. Can anybody help me please?
Thaks in advance.

Comment: `const_iterator` means no modifications.

Comment: @chris `const_iterator` means no modification *through* this iterator. If you want to call `erase`, you already need a non-const way to access the container. The iterator merely provides the position where to modify, so the restriction has been lifted in C++11.

Comment: I guess this question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15987893/420683 You'd need a more recent version of libstdc++; AFAIK it's fixed now (SVN), but I don't know since which version.

Comment: Not entirely sure about what your comment means. After `erase(it)`, you absolutely must not do `++it`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three bugs here.

```
for (vector<File>::const_iterator it = this->files.begin(); it != this->files.end(); ++it) {
    if (...) erase(it); // break after, no need of ++it in else branch
}
```

**The first bug** is that you incorrectly cut-and-pasted your code into StackOverflow. What you meant to paste was

```
for (vector<File>::const_iterator it = this->files.begin(); it != this->files.end(); ++it) {
    if (...) this->files.erase(it); // break after, no need of ++it in else branch
}
```

**The second bug** is what the compiler is warning you about: there's no way to modify a collection through a `const_iterator`. (EDIT: [Okay, apparently C++11 added such a way, but libstdc++ didn't support it immediately.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987893/c11-erase-using-a-const-iterator)) That's what the `const_` part means! If you want to modify the collection, use a plain old `iterator`:

```
for (vector<File>::iterator it = this->files.begin(); it != this->files.end(); ++it) {
    if (...) this->files.erase(it); // LOOK OUT, THERE'S STILL A BUG
}
```

**The third bug** is that once you call `std::vector::erase` on a collection, all iterators (and `const_iterator`s) into that collection become *unusable*. The Standard terminology for this is that `erase` *invalidates iterators*. (The reason for this is that `std::vector` behaves basically like a big heap-allocated buffer, and calling `resize` on the vector is allowed to do the equivalent of `realloc`<sup>(1)</sup> on the buffer, and calling `erase` is allowed to call `resize` (because if you `erase` half the elements in the vector, you're probably expecting the heap-allocation to shrink accordingly).)

So, what you're trying to do *won't work* using that naive for-loop approach. What you need to do is use a *standard algorithm*, [namely `remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
#include <algorithm>

auto predicate = [](const File& f) { return f.ShouldBeErasedOrWhatever(); }
auto newEndIterator = std::remove_if(this->files.begin(), this->files.end(), predicate);
this->files.erase(newEndIterator, this->files.end());  // erase everything after "newEndIterator"
```

Replace `f.ShouldBeErasedOrWhatever()` with whatever your "`...`" is in the original code. Now you have valid, idiomatic C++11 that does the right thing — with no bugs!

---

<sup>(1)</sup> – Note on "the equivalent of `realloc`": Of course it's not *really* `realloc`; it's really a type-safe process that calls move-constructors and destructors as needed. `vector` knows it's not generally safe to `memcpy` arbitrary objects in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your example code is incorrect and it really is `files.erase(it)`, then `const_iterator` version was only added in C++11 which it looks like you don't have since you're not using `auto`.